# Selective MySQL rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a custom CMS system for a friend and it's almost complete. It's as simple as it can be, admin panel contains a sidebar containing all pages that are availaible for edit and each edit page contains a textarea with a wysiwyg editor. All the pages have the same code and most of the pages work like a dream.

However, some of the pages won't work like they should. All of them save simple text when you type it in, and it becomes visible at the page. The site existed before I started to build this CMS behind it, so it has lots of pages containing loads of text, so I just copied all the text from the original code containing the tags and so on. Like I said, most of it works like a dream, but some parts don't. For example this unordered list doesn't fit in in any table row, and I have no idea why:

```
<h1>Kursseja ja opintoja joita olen suorittanut:</h1>
<ul class="lista">

    <li>Koiranomi  koulutus, (ohjaaja / kouluttaja Paula Speer)  8/2008-12/2009</li>
    <li>Luento ’ Koirien käyttäytyminen uusimman tutkimustiedon valossa’ (luennoitsija Tuire Kaimio, järj. Suuret Laumanvartijarodut ry)  2.9.2008</li>
    <li>Gerard O'Shean näyttelyesittämiskurssi  23.-24.9. 2008</li>
    <li>PDTE yhdistyksen  viikonloppu seminaari 27-28.9.2008</li>
    <li>Koiran luonnonmukainen ruokinta perusluento (luennoitsija Malin Ekblom) 11.11. 2008
    </li>
    <li>Koiran luonnonmukainen ruokinta syventävä luento (luennoitsija Malin Ekblom)  3.12. 2008</li>
    <li>HETI:n Jalostuksen ABC -luentopäivä 10.1.2009</li>
    <li>SKL toko koulutusohjaaja kurssi 3/2009 </li>
    <li>Mejä -leiri, järjestäjä Ulla Honkanen  16-17.5.2009</li>
    <li>Esa K Viitala: Etsintäkoiraleiri 6/2009</li>
    <li>Koulutuspäivä "Postiivisen vahvisteen tekniikka sekä siihen liittyvät välineet” (koulutusneuvoja Tommy Wiren) 8/2009</li>
    <li>Trainers Choice koulutustekniikan peruskurssi eli kanakurssi  I   23.25.10.2009</li>
    <li>SKL kasvattajan peruskurssi  14-15.11.2009</li>
    <li>Liikkuminen ja kivun vaikutus koiran käytökseen (luennoitsija Leena Piira) 13.2.2010</li>
    <li>James Serpell seminaari  15.5.2010</li>
    <li>KIVA-teamin rotutuntemusviikonloppu (kouluttaja David Selin) 29.-30.5.2010</li>
    <li>Naksutin koulutus seminaari (kouluttaja Morten Egtvedt) 12.6.2010</li>
    <li>Trainers Choice koiulutustekniikan peruskurssi eli kanakurssi  II   2-4.7.2010</li>
    <li>KIVA TEAM tunne koirasi kurssi 11.-12.9 / 9.-10.10. / 6.-7.11 2010 </li>
    <li>Trainers Choice koulutustekniikan peruskurssi eli kanakurssi III 25-28.11.2010</li>

</ul>
```

Here's the file that updates the database:

```
<? $pagename = 'Location:http://edit.xxx.fi/pages/'.$_POST[PageName];?>
<?php 
include 'mysqlconnection.php';
mysql_query("UPDATE Content SET Content='$_POST[edit]' WHERE PageName='$_POST[PageName]'");
mysql_close($con);
?>
<?php 
header($pagename);
?>
```

And here's the admin panel part that contains the textarea that updates the content:

```
<div class="content">
                <?php include 'sidebar.php';
                $pagename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>
                    <form action="save.php" method="post" style="margin-left:400px; height:600px; overflow:hidden; width:530px; margin-top:-1px;">
                        <p>Editoi sivun <strong><? echo $pagename; ?></strong> sisältöä<br>
                        <small style="font-size:10px;">Huom: Tällä sivulla oleva koulutuslista estää sivun tallentumisen tietokantaan jostain syystä, eli koulutuslista on tallennettu suoraan Susanna sivun lähdekoodiin. Sinne pitää lisätä tiedot käsin. </small></p>

                        <textarea class="editor"
                        name="edit" style="width:500px; height:300px;"><?php 
        include 'mysqlconnection.php';
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Content WHERE PageName='$pagename'"); 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

  echo $row['Content'];
  }?></textarea>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<? echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?>" name="PageName">
                        <input type="submit" value="Tallenna" class="submit">
                    </form>
                    <br>
                    <div style="height:600px; width:500px; border:1px solid black; margin-left:400px; position:absolute; left:300px; top:500px; overflow:auto;">
                    <?php 
        include 'mysqlconnection.php';
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Content WHERE PageName='$pagename'"); 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

  echo $row['Content'];
  }?>
                    </div>
```

I'm using a htaccess rewrite for the pagenames to remove the file-extension, so don't get a misunderstanding on that.

What I'm possibly doing wrong on this? The data updates to the database when using phpmyadmin, but then ä and ö are not working correctly, just displaying this:�.

Comment: Are you storing this in a `VARCHAR` (which is subject to the 65535 byte row length limit)? Try changing the column to a `TEXT`/`MEDIUMTEXT`/`LONGTEXT` type, or if you want it to be charset agnostic, `BLOB`/`MEDIUMBLOB`/`LONGBLOB`...

Comment: Yeah, it is TEXT. http://i47.tinypic.com/s278f4.png

Comment: I note that your charset for storage is set to `latin1_swedish_ci` - try `utf8_general_ci`?

Comment: I changed it, still doesn't save the unordered list that I mentioned in any row.

Comment: What error do you get when you try? Even if the query doesn't fail completely, you'll probably find you get a result from `mysql_error()`. Also (I'm sure you are aware/have been told this before but it must be said) *please* do your utmost to avoid developing new code using the `mysql_*` functions, use MySQLi or PDO_mysql instead (I personally recommed PDO). The charset issue was not so much for the failed INSERT/UPDATE, and more to try and fix the �s

Comment: And I can only use MySQL, because of my webhost.

Comment: Try `echo`ing the generated query and running it in phpMyAdmin (I'm assuming the host provide this?). I thought that might be the case with hosting limitations - but if they limit you there where else do they limit you? Maybe it's time to shop around for hosting, there are plenty of inexpensive hosts who provide better access to the newer technologies...

Comment: how to echo the generated query?

Comment: Instead of `mysql_query("UPDATE ...");` do `echo "UPDATE ...";`

Comment: Actually your problem may be a simple problem of not escaping your input (I see a `'` in the HTML), try changing the line to `mysql_query("UPDATE Content SET Content='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['edit'])."' WHERE PageName='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PageName'])."'");`

Comment: And bingo! Thank you. What does the 'escaping your input' mean actually, I'm not that good with php and MySQL, just the basics.

Comment: [All you need to know about SQL injection and escaping database input](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');
```

and ensure your database is storing those characters (field collation set to utf8_swedish_ci or similar).

If not then

SET CHARACTER SET utf8

SET NAMES utf8

Comment: It's not the charset... I know.

Answer (score 0):

The �'s are displayed because of character set problem. Best way to avoid it, is to change everything to UTF-8 encoding.

And like DaveRandom said, if parts of the text is just cut off, problem might be in wrong column type. I would also suggest you to escape all characters before inserting them to database.

Comment: It has always saved the content if it just saves it, and the pages that it won't save, are not longer than any other page.

Comment: And the � is only displayed if I save the data from phpmyadmin, if I save it from the textarea, they work correctly.